# gradle distZip rename archive

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to use a specific name to the distributable zip archive created by distZip task. I used below code

```
distZip {
        archiveName baseName+'-'+version+'-bin.zip'
}
```

Generated archive contains 'baseName+'-'+version+'-bin' folder in it.

```
    jar -tvf baseName-version-bin.zip 
        0 Mon Feb 24 15:48:02 CST 2014   baseName-version-bin/
     81462 Mon Feb 24 15:48:02 CST 2014  baseName-version-bin/baseName-version.jar
         0 Mon Feb 24 15:48:02 CST 2014  baseName-version-bin/lib/
    6329376 Fri Feb 07 09:37:28 CST 2014 baseName-version-bin/lib/a.jar
    6329376 Fri Feb 07 09:37:28 CST 2014 baseName-version-bin/lib/b.jar
```

All the jars were placed inside this directory. I just want to rename the archive and not disturb the contents in it. I was expecting 'baseName-version' directory without '-bin' suffix inside the zip.

How do I alter the name of archive alone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it to work by configuring `doLast` to rename the built archive.

```
distZip {
    doLast {
        file("$destinationDir/$archiveName").renameTo("$destinationDir/$baseName-$version-bin.zip")
    }
}
```

Comment: My idea was to end with both versioned archive name AND a copy labeled 'latest'. E.g. `mypackage-v1.0.0.zip` and `mypackage-latest.zip`.
I've had to make a copy of a file INTO a tmp subdir, then "rename" it to the dir where output lives, and finally remove tmp.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it as follows:

```
distZip {
    archiveName "$baseName-$version-bin.zip"
}

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            eachFile {
                it.path = it.path.replace('-bin', '')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing is, for adding such suffix like *-bin* better way (and compatible with maven) would be using *classifier* property. I'm using *java-library-distribution* plugin but I believe with *distribution* plugin it should work the same (considering you are using maven plugin as well). Then it is enough you do it like:

```
distZip {
    classifier = 'bin'
}

distributions {
    main {
        baseName = archivesBaseName
        contents {
            eachFile {
                it.path = it.path.replace("-$distZip.classifier", '')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
apply plugin: 'application'
```

While using the `application` plugin, this is how changed the file name:

```
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = "watch"
        version = ""
        contents {
            from('.') {
                include '*.yml'
                into "bin"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This generated files `watch.tar` & `watch.zip`.